# Share war across tomcats on multiple machines

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a deployment environment consisting of a tomcat deployed on a VM and accessed via a load balancer. At specific loads extra vms will be spawned, their tomcats fired and added to the load balancer. (doing this using aws auto scale)
But due to this if i have to change a single jsp i am forced to go and make the change on each active vm. Is there any way that i can keep my war file/webapps on a single machine and tomcats on all the vms access the same ? So then my change will have to be done at a single place.

Same problem in simple terms: can tomcats on multiple machines share a war file on single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application server does not provide this functionality, you'll have to do this for your own. (out of context: JBoss/WildFly provides the so called domain mode, where several servers are in one server group. The deployment is performed on a controller server.)

I think the easiest way would be to have a central file system, which will be (read-only-)mounted into your  VM's, which will be the folder, the tomcat deploys its applications from. The problem in this scenario is, you cannot run two different versions of a application at the same time...

regards,

slowy